# Cursor offset with jQuery (not caret)

Tags: jquery, cursor

I'm trying to get the offset or position of the cursor on a single web page. Let's say I move the mouse to the middle of the screen, I then want to know the offset. For example

left: 603 px
top: 521 px

from the coordinate 0,0 of the page.

So the question is, is it possible to get the cursor coordinates with jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I can use the event that avaiable in jQuery, for example;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("body").live("click", get_coords);

});

function get_coords(event){
    console.log(event.clientX);
        console.log(event.clientY);
}
```

Thanks anyway!